# Powershell: rename files that contain certain charactors

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm uploading lots of files into SharePoint from our map drives and SharePoint is displaying errors because it does not like file names with characters with ampersand "p&l.xls" and with 2 full stops "XMas..xls".

I want to replaced the ".." with just one dot "."

replace Ampersand with the word "and"

How do I go about changing the file names in a script?

Answer (score 0):

In powershell, use Get-childitem (gci) to get existing filenames $files, we replace the characters that we do not want:

```
$files = gci -filter "*&*.xls" |select fullname
foreach ($file in $files) {
   $filename = $file.fullname
   $newFilename = $filename.Replace("&", "and")
   $newFilename = $newfilename.Replace("..", ".")
   rename-item $filename $newFilename
}
```

You can use -path "LocationWhereYourFilesAre" to specify where your files are if target files are not in the current working directory.